# Script to Toggle Fullscreen Area (Blender 2.8)

Tags: python, scripting

I am working on a script to automatically take screenshots of a dataset of .stl meshes and I’d like to have only the .stl object framed, that is with all menus, tools and other buttons hidden. The result I am trying to achieve with a script can be reproduced with the CTRL + ALT + Space keyboard shortcut in the UI.
This has already been discussed [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/fullscreen-hide-all-windows/613087), although it’s not working as desired for me. I have adapted the script so it works on Blender 2.8 as explained [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123611/registering-classes-in-blender-2-8), to no avail.
Also, although my issue is similar to that described [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154246/script-to-view-animation-preview-panel-in-fullscreen), it is neither working for me.
Could anyone help?
Cheers!

Comment: What *exactly* does not work? Could you share the current state of your code?

Comment: Compared to last issue referenced, since I'm not working with Animations that was obviously not working for me. Furthermore, all gizmos and overlays were still visible. Found the solution and shared it down below. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 4):

Solved. What I was looking for was indeed really close to the issue discussed in [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154246/script-to-view-animation-preview-panel-in-fullscreen) post.
Here's the code snippet that does the work:

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context.copy()

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        context['area'] = area
        bpy.ops.screen.screen_full_area(context, use_hide_panels=True)
        bpy.context.space_data.show_gizmo = False
        bpy.context.space_data.overlay.show_overlays = False
```

Hope it can be of some help to others!